# Assembling a function as needed and computing it fast

Tags: c++, lambda, linker, artificial-intelligence, interpreter

There are interpreted languages out there, such as Lisp, Tcl, Perl, etc., that make it easy to define a lambda/proc/sub within your code during runtime and to evaluate it within the same session.

There are compiled languages out there, such as C++, that would execute much faster than the interpreted ones, yet defining a function within a compiled program during runtime and executing it is not easy, if at all possible.

The problem here is to do the following:

1. Define a function during runtime: for example, based on the initial input data derive an analytic model of the data.
2. Execute the above function fast in a loop: for example, apply the derived analytic model for analysing incoming data.

One solution that I saw was not very pretty:

1. A procedure representing the analytic model was derived in embedded Tcl based on the initial input data.
2. A lookup table was created by evaluating the procedure in Tcl on an array of sample points that, optimistically speaking, would cover the applicability range.
3. The lookup table was passed from the Tcl interpreter back to the binary (which was developed in C++).
4. Then the incoming data was analysed by interpolating between "close enough" values in the lookup table.

The above solution works, but has quite a few problems, both conceptual and computational. Thus the question: is it possible to define a function purely within C++ and make it available for execution within the same runtime session?

Conceptually speaking, is it possible to do something like create a function as a string, compile it in-memory, and somehow link it back into the binary that's being executed?

Comment: There are many efficient Lisp compilers out there. There are JIT-compiled VMs like .NET and JVM. There are embeddable C compilers (tcc, clang). It's also pretty easy to generate LLVM IR directly, with all the benefits of a powerful optimising compiler.

Comment: And even C++ interpreters are widely used, see CINT and ROOT.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want something working right out of the box have a look at [ExprTK](http://partow.net/programming/exprtk/). If you want to write an expression parser yourself check out [Boost Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com).

An alternative would be to create C++ code on the fly, compile it as a shared library (plugin) and load it at runtime. This would probably be the fastest solution.

Comment: Thanks, at the 1st glance Boost Spirit looks promising. Do you know how fast it is? Does it generate optimized binary code that can be executed in a loop sufficiently fast?

Comment: A parser written with Spirit would typically create an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST), which is simply an aggregation of operations and values. Here is an example: [Boost Spirit AST example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/example./qi/calc2_ast.cpp). Hence the result will generally be slower than optimized compiled code. If speed is your major concern you should go for the last suggestion.

Comment: @Michael Boost.Spirit is ok for parsing, but the evaluation of the AST is going to be the big killer in performance. Also developing with Boost.Spirit requires a lot of patience and most compilers can barely cope with anything more complex than a simple +/-/* calculator style grammar - compile times are insanely long and all sorts of tricks have to be done like breaking grammars into multiple files etc.